# Call SConstruct from R

Tags: r, path, environment, scons

How can I call a sconstruct script from R (e.g. in Rstudio)? I'd like to call SCons and, ideally, also read the output. So that I can get the print from e.g. `scons --tree=all` as a string.

If I run `> system("scons")`
I get: `sh: scons: command not found`

Setting the path `Sys.setenv(PATH=paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"), "/path/to/my/sconstruct", sep=":"))` doesn't help.

However, any other command works. E.g. if I have a Python script (in the same directory), I can call it as: `> system('python test.py')`
and get the expected: `Hello Rld!` back. `>system('ls')` lists the `SConstruct`, so I'm in the right work directory.

Calling from a Python script also works, eg: `from subprocess import call` `call('scons')` evokes the SConstruct as expected. However, calling that Python script from R -- doesn't work.

It appears as there is something in the R environment setting that I got wrong.

I'm on OS, but a portable solution would be fantastic!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to either be in the directory where the SConstruct is, specify it's file or use -C to change directory to it.
I don't know R or what the syntax is.

```
Sys.setenv(PATH=paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"), "/path/to/my/sconstruct", sep=":"))
```

Should likely be:

```
Sys.setenv(PATH=paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"), "/path/to/scons", sep=":"))
```